# Bandpass Filter Shape in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, filter, signal-processing

I was trying to make a bandpass filter. While i was working on it, i noticed something odd. 
The frequency response of the filter is OK(scipy.signal.freqz). But when i applied it on a sine signal the shape of the filter changes.

Figure 3 = Spectrum of signal

Figure 4 = Frequency response of the filter according to freqz() function

Figure 1 = Spectrum of filter applied signal

Finally why do the shape of filter(also magnitude) is changed when it is applied on a signal?

[image: Spectrum of my signal]

[image: Response of filter according to freqz function]

[image: Filter applied signal spectrum]

```
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter, buttord, freqz
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

t = np.arange(0, 8192, 1)
data = 1+np.sin(.15*np.pi*t + np.pi/2)

b, a = butter(6, [0.35, 0.55], btype='band')

y = lfilter(b, a, data)

y = np.fft.rfft(y)
y = np.abs(y)

x = np.fft.rfft(data)
x = np.abs(x)


w, h = freqz(b, a, worN=4096)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(np.arange(0,4097,1),y)

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(np.arange(0,8192,1), data)

plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(np.arange(0,4097,1), x)

plt.figure(4)
plt.plot(np.arange(0,4096,1),np.abs(h))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you share the code that generated these visualizations?  I think it would be helpful.

Comment: Added the code, sorry my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply the filter you are multiplying the fourier transform (i.e. the spectrum) of the signal f(w) with the filter function g(w). So the output in the time domain is IFFT(f(w) g(w)) and just g(w)f(w) in the spectral domain, which is your figure 1. It is clear that the product will be different to both signal and filter. In your case the filter and signal do not overlap very much, which leads to a somewhat strange result. Try adding a second sin wave with angular frequency 0.5 pi and you will see a very different result.

Comment: Thank you. When i tried with lots of sine function it worked as you said

http://s32.postimg.org/loh24vtrp/wow.png